# how to convert algebraically $(1/3)^{n-1}$ to $1 +(1/3)^n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am learning infinite series, and I find that geometric series
 $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{n-1}$$
is the same as
$$1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left (\frac{1}{3}\right)^{n},$$
so I think that both can be algebraically equivalent.
How can I prove that $$\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{n-1} = 1 + \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{n}\;???$$

Comment: It's not true that $\left(\dfrac13\right)^{n-1}=1+\left(\dfrac13\right)^n$; for example, $n=1$:  $\left(\dfrac13\right)^0\ne1+\dfrac13$

Comment: +1 i edited the question

Comment: formatting note:  to get $\infty$, type `$\infty$`, not `$\inf$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't prove that $\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^{n-1} = 1 + \left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^{n},$

because it's not true, but with $n=m-1,$

$$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{m-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{n}
=\left(\frac13\right)^0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{n}  
=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{n}.$$

Comment: +1here you pulled $$\frac{1}{3}^0$$ from inside the series as it equals 1...what if it is $$\sum_{n=1}^{\inf} 5(\frac{1}{5})^{n-1}$$???

Comment: $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty5\left(\dfrac15\right)^{n-1}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty5\left(\dfrac15\right)^n=5+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty5\left(\dfrac15\right)^n$

Comment: also after getting $$\frac{1}{3}^{0}$$ out now n=1 and m=1  so first term of $$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{m-1}$$ is equal to first term of $$1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{n-1}$$

Comment: you give me very good answers. i am trying to understand them...thanks alot.i will accept your answer and try to understand it

Comment: shifting the index by $1$ for the infinite sums reminds me of [Hilbert's hotel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_paradox_of_the_Grand_Hotel)